# wp_insert_category() setting the 'cat_ID' gives not array error

Tags: plugin-development, categories

I'm writing a plugin that automatically creates a bunch of stuff ie categories and child categories. But when I use the following code to create the categories: (from [wp codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category))

```
//Create Post Categories
$my_cat = array(
    'cat_ID' => 1146,
    'cat_name' => 'Newcastle Community News & Views', 
    'category_description' => '', 
    'category_nicename' => 'news', 
    'category_parent' => '',
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
);
$my_cat_id = wp_insert_category($my_cat);
```

It gives me the following error.

> ```
> Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in /home/newcastl/public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 2535
> ```

With the id in '' isnt working either.
I have to set the ID so I can refer to it when using sub-cats.
Thanks!

Comment: what i found out so far:
when i use 
          'cat_ID' => array(3352),
it doenst give me the error msg but it creates a category with the ID 1. Probably because there is one value in the array. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are creating a category, why you are passing the `cat_ID` value?

Comment: Yeah I actually realized that it is not possible to give an id if you create a new category. The codex is not so clear on this and I didn't know. I have a solution now and will post as soon as the system lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the solution I found:
You are not meant to set IDs when creating new objects like categories. Instead I created the parent categories first using something like

```
$my_cat = array(
    'cat_name' => 'Community News & Views', 
    'category_nicename' => 'news', 
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
);
$my_cat_id = wp_insert_category($my_cat);
```

In a second step I create the child categories using

```
    $parent_term = term_exists( 'news', 'category' );
$parent_term_id = $parent_term['term_id'];
$my_cat = array(
    'cat_name' => 'Business Articles', 
    'category_nicename' => 'business-articles', 
    'category_parent' => $parent_term_id,
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
);
$my_cat_id = wp_insert_category($my_cat);
```

Note: You cannot create Parent and Child categories at the same time because the parent category has to exist, when you create the Child category 
Note also: `term_exists( 'news', 'category' );` uses the $slug as first argument. The codex is not so clear on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wp_insert_term() in place of wp_insert_category(). You can use the following code:

```
wp_insert_term(
 'Newcastle Community News & Views', 
 'category', 
  array(
     'description'=>'',
     'slug'=>'',
     'parent'=>''
  )
);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work either. You are not supposed to give id's when creating new stuff. The codex is not so clear on this and I didn't know. I have a solution now and will post as soon as the system lets me.